# What is the recommended way (if any) to install the KeeFox Add-On on Mac?

Tags: macos, firefox-extensions, keepassx

I use KeePassX 2.0 on Mac OS 10.10.5 and Firefox 43.0.4.

I would like to use the KeeFox add-on, but on the Mozilla page "Not available for your platform" shows up.

Nevertheless I think I saw somebody using it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/luckyrat/KeeFox/issues/22) on the developer's Github page (scroll to the end) you should be able to go to the [developer page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keefox/) and install the developer version.

The documentation isn't that great though, I was interested in this as well and wasn't able to get this working yet.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work for me either. Maybe KeyPassX is not compatible with KeeFox.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [KyPass Companion](http://www.kyuran.be/software/kypass4mac) that have the KeePassHttp plugin built-in and the [passifox](https://github.com/pfn/passifox) extension for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like now KeePass (2.34) works terribly with Mono (4.6.2) on macOS (Sierra 10.12.1). I don't really understand if it's an issue of KeePass or Mono. But KeePass crashes each time I'm trying to receive password through PassIFox (despite of the fact that connection finished successfully). I can't even search for entry. Maybe it some issue in working with Windows.Forms. Maybe something else, it's not easy to understand the problem. Anyway it seems that the developers are not going to fix it.

https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/d567f555/

https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/bugs/1268/

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21358

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no accepted answer here I thought I would suggest MacPass.

https://github.com/mstarke/MacPass.

MacPass is a native KeePass port.

It's autotype feature can be a replacement for a separate browser plugin. Not needing to install a browser plugin might even be preferable for many people.
https://github.com/mstarke/MacPass

There is also a HTTP plugin to allow it to work with browser plugins (MacPassHTTP).

Comment: Software Recommendation say what!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MacPass](http://macpassapp.org/) to manage your keepass-database.

In order to use the Passwords in your Browser use the Plugin
[MacPassHTTP](https://github.com/MacPass/MacPassHTTP/releases)

Extract and copy the resulting file to the MacPass plugin folder at ~/Library/Application Support/MacPass/. Restart MacPass if you're already running it.

Open MacPass Settings and under Plugins check "Load unsecure Plugins" and "Allow remote connections"

For Firefox install
[KeePassHTTP-Connector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keepasshttp-connector/)

For Chrome you can use [chromiPass](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeipass/ompiailgknfdndiefoaoiligalphfdae)

Comment: Can you expand this a little with what to do with those pieces (more of the "how")?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

bitwarden is a free and open source application. It has browser extensions for Firefox and Chrome, and mobile apps on iOS and Android.

Transfer you data from KeePassX:
Database > Export to CSV file

Create an account at bitwarden:
https://vault.bitwarden.com/#/

Tools > Import Data > KeepassX (csv)

Comment: Can you go into a little detail on how the OP would transfer the data?